# atomic append to google spreadsheet by gspread

Tags: google-sheets-api, gspread

The append in the sense of not trivially using `append_row` in which it will write at the end of the spreadsheet itself but at the end of contents that potentially could be appended by other users (from google drive for example).

Is it possible? Does gspread support say lock the file (or lock certain rows to be non-editable). I scanned through their doc but didn't find any interface seems relevant.

If not, are there any library that could do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Class Protection`. A protected range can protect either a static range of cells or a named range. It may include unprotected regions. The  [`canEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#canedit) method determines whether the user has permission to edit the protected range of sheets. You may also use  [`getEditors`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#geteditors) were in you get the list of editors for the protected range or sheet. Throws an exception if the user does not have permission to edit the protected range or sheet.